# Using `class` keyword followed by an undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, templates

The following hpp and cpp files are an excerpt from a large program that I am working with. It will compile with `g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`.

```cpp
// a.hpp

#include <memory>

class A
{
    std::unique_ptr<class A_impl> my;
};
```

```cpp
//a.cpp

#include "a.hpp"

int main()
{}
```

But I don't understand about the syntax on the line regarding the unique pointer.

Questions:

1. What's the syntax for `<class A_impl>`? What's this (putting `class` before an undeclared identifier) called? Is it doing a "forward declaration" on `A_impl` or what? I haven't said anything about the identifier `A_impl`. How come the compiler is okay with that?
2. If this happens to be possibly related to any "design pattern", please help me identify it.

Please point out the right direction.

Comment: [Elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier)

Comment: Almost equivalent to `class A_impl; std::unique<A_impl> my;`

Comment: Thanks @Jean-BaptisteYunès If it were written in this way, I would be completely fine with that. Never seen this before -- putting forward declaration as part of another declaration.

Comment: @JeanBaptisteYunes Almost? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59609538/1116364

Comment: @DanielJour Can't remember details but there is a scoping difference (maybe not in that example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it doing a "forward declaration" on `A_impl` or what?

Exactly. What's probably confusing about it is that it's using an [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier) in the template argument to do so. [Differences to a "normal" forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59609538/1116364)

> I haven't said anything about the <s>identifier</s> *type* `A_impl`. How come the compiler is okay with that?

`std::unique_ptr` can be instantiated with an incomplete type - just like a raw pointer.

> If this happens to be possibly related to any "design pattern", how can I identify it?

[The PIMPL - "pointer to implementation" idiom.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Do you agree with the comment to the question that `elaborated type specifier` applies to this case?

Comment: "Elaborated type specifier" definitively applies ... that's basically the term of that syntax construct ... which is also used in a "normal" forward declaration. I'm not sure about the differences...

Comment: Up voted! Didn't realize this also works, always used the `class T; std::unique_ptr<T> p; myself.`