# Difference between forward declaration in argument vs "normal" forward declaration

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, elaborated-type-specifier

What is - if any - the difference between a forward declaration in a (template) argument (using an [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier)) and a "normal" forward declaration?

```cpp
void foo(struct bar *);

// vs

struct bar;
void foo(bar *);

// ------ and also -------

std::unique_ptr<class Baz> one;

// vs

class Baz;
std::unique_ptr<Baz> two;
```

Comment: Possibly related / useful https://stackoverflow.com/q/10902518/1116364

Comment: Historical note - there was a difference in C (and this probably should be regadred as a design flaw) but there is no difference in C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's begin by noting that "forward declaration" is a colloquialism used to refer to a certain common practical use of certain kinds of declarations. There is no such thing as a forward declaration as far as the C++ standard is concerned. There are just declarations.

With that in mind, I believe that there is no difference between

```cpp
void foo(struct bar *);
```

and

```cpp
struct bar;
```

as far as their effect on the name `bar` is concerned. Both declarations end up introducing the name of the struct `bar` if there is no previous declaration that already did so.

The relevant paragraph in C++17 would seem to be [[basic.lookup.elab]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.elab#2) (emphasis mine):

> If the *elaborated-type-specifier* is introduced by the *class-key* and this lookup does not find a previously declared *type-name*, or […] **the *elaborated-type-specifier* is a declaration that introduces the *class-name*** as described in [basic.scope.pdecl].

If an *elaborated-type-specifier* that doesn't contain a *nested-name-specifier* is encountered, unqualified name lookup is performed to see if the name already names a corresponding type. If no previously declared name is found, then the *elaborated-type-specifier* becomes a declaration of the class type of that name…

As pointed out by geza, the one way in which there can be a difference has to do with the scope into which the name is introduced. While

```cpp
struct bar;
```

always introduces the name into the scope in which the declaration appears, an *elaborated-type-specifier* appearing as part of any other kind of declaration will introduce the name into the closest enclosing namespace [[basic.scope.pdecl]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.pdecl#7).

Answer (score 3):

The difference can be the scope the declaration introduced. In case of elaborated type specifier, the declaration is introduced in the closest namespace, and this can make a difference.

For example:

```
struct Foo {
      void fn(struct Bar *);
};
```

Here, `Bar` is declared in the global namespace, not in `Foo`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't declare `struct bar;` beforehand, then `struct bar` might refer to type name declared in an outer scope (which might come from a completely different library). For example:

```
class bar {};
// ...
namespace ns {
    void foo(struct bar *);
}
```

^ Here the parameter of `foo` is pointer to the class `bar` in global scope.

```
class bar {};
// ...
namespace ns {
    struct bar;
    void foo(bar *);
}
```

^ Here the parameter of `foo` is pointer to `ns::bar`.